# Why do we use $\bigoplus_{i=1}^n M_i$ instead of $\prod_{i=1}^n M_i$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I don't understand the difference between $\bigoplus_{i=1}^n M_i$ and $\prod_{i=1}^n M_i$ where $\{M_i\}_{i=1,...,n}$ is a collection of $R-$module. When $I$ is not finite, $$\prod_{i\in I}M_i=\{(x_i)_{i\in I}\mid x_i\in I\}$$ and $$\bigoplus _{i\in I}M_i=\{(x_i)_{i\in I}\mid x_i=0\text{ except for finite number of $i$}\}.$$

But for $I$ finite, it looks to be the same... so what's the difference between them when $I$ is finite ?

Comment: There is no difference when $I$ is finite

Comment: So why using two differents notation for the same thing ? @AlexMathers

Comment: We have the two different notations because they're different when $I$ is infinite

Comment: For general index sets the constructions solve different universal mapping problems, one using linear maps *from each* $M_i$ to a single $R$-module and the other using linear maps from a single $R$-module *to each* $M_i$. In the notation of the module of all linear mappings, $\prod_i  {\rm Hom}(M_i,N) \cong {\rm Hom}(\bigoplus_i M_i,N)$ and $\prod_i {\rm Hom}(N,M_i) \cong {\rm Hom}(N,\prod_i M_i)$.  Look inside the Hom-modules on the right and you see the direct sum and direct product playing different roles. It is hard to appreciate the distinction if you look at finite index (contd.)

Comment: sets only. A simpler (related) distinction: a direct sum of modules is spanned by its component modules even for infinite index sets, but the direct product is not.

Comment: For rings $R_i$ with identity, the direct product $\prod_i R_i$ is again a ring with identity, but the direct sum $\bigoplus_i R_i$ is *not* a ring with identity when the index set is infinite.

Answer (score 2):

In the case that the $M_i$ are ideals, $\prod_{i \in I} M_i$ is sometimes used for the product of the ideals. Thus, to avoid confusion, $\bigoplus_{i \in I} M_i$ is used instead.

Answer (score 0):

For finite cases they are identical and either and both can be used interchangably without problem. The reason why the notation exists is because for the infinite case they are NOT the same. One is the universal product construct, the other is the coproduct. Both of them garantuees the existence of a homomorphism of certain types, however one is surjective and the other is injective.